# Stub generated using Axis2 Webservice forming new connection for redirect URL...Need same TCP connection...!

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am badly stuck with a SOAP based integration using Axis2 framework for generation of client stubs from the Server WSDL. The scenario is as follows :

1. There is always a login API call first, which gives a Success response in SOAP body and  Temporary Redirect in HTTP header. Also provides a URL which contains the session ID in the Location field of HTTP Header.
2. The next API call is required to be made at this redirect location. IN THE SAME TCP CONNECTION, for getting a proper response.

   1. Now, the problem is, as a part of Webservice implementation using Axis2 generated stubs, I need to reload this redirect URL and re-instantiate it as --- "stub=new Stub(newurl)"
   2. As soon as this is done, it creates a new TCP connection and so, the next request gives the response as "session ID invalid" because it goes out-of-sync with login API.

I have tried everything mentioned as a solution in this forum and nothing is working out.
For e.g --

---

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpConnectionManager);


            ServiceClient serviceClient = stub._getServiceClient();
            Options opts = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();

            opts.setTo(new EndpointReference(prop.getProperty("target_end_point_url")));
            opts.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
            opts.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);

            serviceClient.setOptions(opts);

            stub._setServiceClient(serviceClient);
```

---

Similarly, I have tried many other options too. But it's not helpful at all.

Comment: Have you tried with [Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/samples.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Faced exactly the same issue.
Following steps solved the issue.
 1. Using HttpClient, perform login. Don't use stub object to perform login.
 2. Use the Location Header URL, to create new stub object i.e. stub = new Stub(locationURL). (Your existing options setting should be retained.)
3. There is a default timeout, by which server disconnects the TCP connection. In my case it was 50 seconds. Hence as soon as i performed login in step 1, i execute a timer every 40 seconds, to send an empty requests to new Location URL using HeadMethod of same HttpClient object.